# How i can use protobufjs in angular2-Typescript rest service

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanted to use protobuf in my rest service call of angular2 with typescript project. I am new to typescript, javascript and angular 2.

Please guide me how protobuf can be used.

Comment: The best start is to read the documentation.

Comment: can you suggest any. I search online but those are bit confusing, I want document related to typescript implementation but I found most documents are related to javascript implementation